# Error with Chartjs radar pointLabels color Scriptable

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Refering to documentation (3.4.1) the color of labels in chartjs radar chart is a scriptable and customizable via options.scales.r.pointLabels.color, I have been trying to set a different label color for each tick.

The problem is that when passing a function as the property value as  explained in the scriptable documentation the context does not contain the property **dataIndex** (as is the example), and the **index** property (which is instead present) only goes up to 10 and is missing in further labels:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        r: {
            pointLabels: {
                color: function(context) {
                    return Colors.r[context.dataIndex];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also found posts that declared that you could achieve what  I need also by directly passing the Colors array in the property but also in that case it does not work past the 10th label

Is it a bug? Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a bug in chart.js. It generates the context for the labels on the size of the ticks array so as a workaround you can specify the count in the ticks array to be the same size as the amount of pointLabels you have

```js
scales: {
    r: {
        ticks: {
            count: 24
        },
        pointLabels: {
            color: (ctx) => {
                return ctx.index % 2 === 0 ? 'green' : 'red'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/PomZgoW

Comment: I set the number of ticks and assigned the colors array directly as parameter value and it worked perfectly. TYVM

Comment: @bUxEE when chart.js v3.5 comes out this should be fixed without needing to set the amount of ticks to the amount of pointLabels: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/9373